# Internal Server Error

Tags: field, error-message, error, server

I am trying to edit fields.  When I go to `Settings->Fields` and then click on a field, I get a message that reads:

```
Internal Server Error

Craft\Model and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "availableAssetSources".
```

Then I looked in the utility logs under server info, it reads:

```
Level:  error
Category:   exception.Twig_Error_Runtime
Message:    exception 'CException' with message 'Craft\Model and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "availableAssetSources".' in /home/christen/6989-CLG-Web/craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php:266
```

I am including the code written on line 266, in case it helps:

```
throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','{class} and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "{name}".',
```

What does all of this mean and how can I fix it?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You're running [Craft 2.6+](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2771) and you've got an older version of the [Redactor I](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorI) plugin installed that isn't Craft 2.6 compatible.  If you [download the latest](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorI/archive/1.1.0.zip) version of the plugin and install it, the error will go away and Redactor I will work as usual.

Comment: Brad Bell... you the man!!!